# Insert Failure On Underlying Tables of Indexed View

Tags: sql-server, indexing, view

I read [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20180409185333/http://sqlblog.com/blogs/alexander_kuznetsov/archive/2009/06/02/be-ready-to-drop-your-indexed-view.aspx) about the pitfalls of indexed views in SQL Server, but I don't understand what the workaround is. The use case in the article showing the lock contention seems to be a reasonable/useful application of an indexed view.

Is there any way in which an indexed view can be used as described in the article without running into the problems raised?

Edit (copied important parts from the link):

Indexed views may increase lock contention.

It is very easy to demonstrate. Create the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.ChildTable(ChildID INT NOT NULL 
  CONSTRAINT PK_ChildTable PRIMARY KEY,
  ParentID INT NOT NULL,
  Amount INT NOT NULL);
GO
```

From one tab in SSMS, run this script:

`BEGIN TRAN;
INSERT INTO dbo.ChildTable(ChildID, ParentID, Amount)
  VALUES(1,1,1);`

From another tab, run a similar one:

```
BEGIN TRAN;
INSERT INTO dbo.ChildTable(ChildID, ParentID, Amount)
VALUES(2,1,1);
ROLLBACK;
```

Note that both inserts complete, they do not block each other. Rollback in both tabs, and create an indexed view:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.ChildTableTotals WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT ParentID, 
COUNT_BIG(*) AS ChildRowsPerParent, 
SUM(Amount) AS SumAmount
FROM dbo.ChildTable
GROUP BY ParentID;
GO
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX ChildTableTotals_CI 
ON dbo.ChildTableTotals(ParentID);
```

Rerun the two inserts. Note that the second one does not complete; it is blocked. The reason is very simple: the first insert modifies the corresponding entry in the indexed view, so the insert acquires and holds a lock on it.

Comment: You should [edit] the question and cite the **relevant passages** (don't just dump the whole thing!) of the article so that this question can be useful in the future even if the link goes done.

Comment: That's a pretty old article you have there (over 10 years old), and there's been significant changes to SQL Server since then; including to the cardinality estimator. None of the versions that were out when that article was released are even supported any more (at all). I can't say that what that article says isn't still true, but I certainly wouldn't take it at face value after so many years. Personally I would try to replicate the problems it describes in the Article in a Modern Sandbox server and see if it is still a problem.

Comment: Thanks guys, I've edited to include the important part of the article, and I was able to re-create the issue with MSSQL 2016